# Figuring out which (failing) CMD script is running on login

Tags: windows

When logging into Windows in the last few months, typically on restart after an update, I am greeted with a failed CMD process in a terminal. I have no idea what this is - if this somehow is my own doing, due to some program I installed years ago updating or the upgrade to Windows 11H2. Who knows. I want to know how I can figure out what process/shell script is failing.

The string "Systemet finner ikke angitt fil" is Norwegian for "Cannot find the designated file", so it seems as if something is trying to run a script at startup that since has been moved/deleted.

[image: failing cmd prompt]

Comment: Use `regedit` to check under the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor` for the presence of an item named `AutoRun`. If you find it, then it will contain the problematic script.

Comment: Check Event viewer and/or Task scheduler for the tasks that are set to run at logon.

Comment: Nothing in the Task Scheduler that did not complete successfully when invoking manually. Checked the  events without spotting anything in particular, but there are a lot of categories ...

Comment: @harrymc No such key. Neither under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/..

Answer (score 2):

AutoRuns is a program that lists everything (including both locations mentioned in the comments above) that starts when the computer starts.

This utility, which has the most comprehensive knowledge of auto-starting locations of any startup monitor, shows you what programs are configured to run during system bootup or login, and when you start various built-in Windows applications like Internet Explorer, Explorer and media players. These programs and drivers include ones in your startup folder, Run, RunOnce, and other Registry keys. Autoruns reports Explorer shell extensions, toolbars, browser helper objects, Winlogon notifications, auto-start services, and much more. Autoruns goes way beyond other autostart utilities.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns

[image]

Comment: nothing pops up as something special. The only cmd related thing is the AlternateShell thing that is already present in your screenshot, but not sure how to debug that further.